# How to use QR code scan to check if the app is installed or not ? and redirect in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code

I'm trying to design an application using Flutter framework where i need two features using QR Code scanner. Features as follows,

1. If the app is installed QR code scanner (when scanning from the app it self) should open a url link in browser (within the app is self)
2. If the app is not installed scanning the QR code from device it self should take the user to play/app store or to a website.

how can i achieve this using flutter and dart? any sample workout will be more than helpful.

Comment: This seems entirely unrelated to flutter or dart

Comment: if its unrelated to dart nor flutter. is there any other solution ? 
cause in the app there will be a QR code scanner where it scans and open a URL link within the app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) or a similar service.
FDL allows you to do exactly what you want.

Basically you specify an app identifier in the console, then in your app's info.plist + manifest.xml you specify the domain you used for the link generation.

The way it works is FDL will try to open the link locally on the device, if the app is already installed then it will launch the app, otherwise you can decide to redirect to a specified URL or to the platform app store and open your app page.

Comment: thank you for the comment and input.  
in this part "if the app is already installed then it will launch the app".
can i perform where from the installed app it self the QR code is being scanned and then it will open another URL link ? + if user scan the QR from device then the installed app opens and redirect the user to a URL link?